# One to zero or one relationship error when create/update related model asp.net EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship

I need to map two entities with one to zero or one relationship. when I create a principal object it works.

I have the following models:

```
//Principal class
public class Sugerencia     
    {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Título")]
            public string Titulo { get; set; }
    //More properties simplified for example
    }
//Related class
public class Resultado
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int SugerenciaID { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ID { get; set;}
        //More properties
    }
```

This is my DbContext Class

```
public class SugerenciaContext : DbContext
{
    public SugerenciaContext() : base("SugerenciaContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Sugerencia> Sugerencias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Resultado> Resultados { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Resultado>()
       .HasRequired(r => r.Sugerencia)
       .WithOptional(s => s.Resultado);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Note the OnModelCreate overriding for map the relationship.

This is the ResultadoController Create actions (POST and GET)

```
//GET
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Sugerencias, "ID", "Titulo");
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //I am retrieving the principal model instance to set resultado.Sugerencia property.
        Sugerencia sugerencia = db.Sugerencias.Find(id);
        if (sugerencia == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
        resultado.Sugerencia = sugerencia;
        return View(resultado);
    }

//POST
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,SugerenciaID,Responsable,Resultados,Fecha")] Resultado resultado, string status)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                resultado.Fecha = System.DateTime.Now;
                Sugerencia sugerencia = db.Sugerencias.Find(resultado.ID);
                if (sugerencia == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                sugerencia.Status = status;
                //Here I am modifying the state property of Sugerencia model.
                db.Entry(sugerencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(resultado).State = resultado.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Sugerencias, "ID", "Titulo", resultado.ID);
            return View(resultado);
        }
```

The error I am getting is triggered in `db.SaveChenges();`line. When I am trying to add a new Resultado model. However when I invoke the Create action for a principal instance which already has a related object in the DB it recreates the object rewriting the values on DB as expected.

In the create view of Resultado controller I have to update one property of Sugerencia model.

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Note I am inserting or modifying the instance. I am debugging via Command Window and setting a breakpoint at that line. When printing resultado and sugerencia variables all properties seem to be valid.

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: The foreign key id needs to be nullable `int?`

Comment: Do you mean set to null the ID in the controller? It is not possible since FK   is not nulleable.

Comment: You need to MAKE the key nullable

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, this is what I think is happening:

```
// This is not needed, by the way, since the previous line should have done this
db.Entry(sugerencia).State = EntityState.Modified;

// This is probably setting resultado's state to Modified, even for new items!
db.Entry(resultado).State = resultado.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
```

First of all, when would you need to set the `resultado` state to `EntityState.Modified` in a Create action? Also, I'm guessing that your model configuration is setting `Resultado.ID` as the foreign key, so when you previously set `resultado.Sugerencia = sugerencia`, `Resultado.ID` was set to a value not equal to zero.

You should be fine with

```
db.Entry(resultado).State = EntityState.Added;
```